# What is the name of this notation for representing set membership?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

What is the name for the membership graph notation used in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62790/kuratowskis-definition-of-ordered-pairs ?  I'd also appreciate a reference to any explanatory resources.

I'd like to understand it a little more, but googling "membership graph" didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for the membership relation.